# Control abaqus command prompt from python

Tags: python, abaqus

For couple of days I am searching for a way to control abaqus command prompt from Python script to run an .py file for abaqus. Actually my main purpose is to extract vonMises data from an .odb file.

I can run my main code to run the abaqus analysis with this code below;

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['C:\SIMULIA\Abaqus\Commands\\abq6131.bat cae noGUI=C:\Users\\acer\Desktop\GereksizDosyalar\macro7.py'], shell=True)
```

This code simply open abaqus command prompt with "abq6131.dat" and run the analysis.

My second code to extract data from .odb file with python is;

```
subprocess.call(['C:\SIMULIA\Abaqus\Commands\\abq6131.bat abaqus python odbMaxMises.py -odb Job-1.odb'], shell=True)
```

but it gives error: Error: ***ERROR: "odbMaxMises.py"  is not an Abaqus database file.

Actually if I manually open abaqus command prompt and write

```
abaqus python odbMaxMises.py -odb Job-1.odb
```

I can get the result. So do you know how to control abaqus command via python? For example I want to write something on python and see it on the abaqus command prompt. Thanks in advance..

Comment: "abq6131.bat abaqus python odbMaxMises.py" the extra `abaqus` should not be there, just `abq6131.bat python odbMaxMises.py..`.  Also when command line testing use the exact same (full path) as you are trying to use in the subprocess call.

Comment: as I always say, different perspectives are way too beneficial. Thanks! @agentp . But do you have any idea about controlling abaqus command line from python ?

Comment: personally i use abaqus cae scripts as the "top level" controlling process.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get something simmilar working using the regular python command in the unix terminal and the following scripts:

File 1 (ran in unix terminal using python file1.py NOT abaqus python...):

```
import os
os.system("abaqus viewer nogui=test.py")
```

File 2 (test.py):

```
import sys
print >> sys.__stdout__, 'It worked'
```

Hope something simmilar works for you.